# rotation of the image in all axes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have pictures of bottle from six sides (front, back, bottom, top, left, right).
I need to implement rotation on all axes using range sliders. That is, when we rotate one slider and then another, the rotation logic should continue from where we left off.

- the first slider rotates the bottle from left to right(back upside down, bottom, front, top,back upside down)
- the second slider rotates the bottle from left to right(back, left, front, right,back)
- the third slider rotates the bottle from left to right(-180deg, -90deg, 0deg, 90deg,180deg)

Now i'am using hardcoded if else blocks to check what image to show depend on slider values

Please help to correctly form the data structure and the implementation of rotations.

[This is how slider looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjJdx.png)

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating 3 map arrays, where you determine the order of the pictures. You can store in a variable what is the currently shown picture. Based on which slider you use, you know what array you should use the next image from. And the slider ticks can represent all the values in the said array. Hope you get where I am trying to lead.